# Python SKLearn training test data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, training-data

This is my first time working on machine learning. I have an assignment to run Logistic and Bayesian Regression from Sklearn on apple stock returns and compare that with linear regression + tensor flow. I am not sure if I am correct in understanding that before I run Logistic Regression I have to train my data set. I was trying to do that my data looks like:

```
Closing_Price   Daily_Returns   Daily_Returns_1 Daily_Returns_2 Daily_Returns_3 Daily_Returns_4 Daily_Returns_5
Date                            
1980-12-22  0.53    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979    -0.085158   -0.040005
1980-12-23  0.55    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979    -0.085158
1980-12-24  0.58    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979
1980-12-26  0.63    0.082692    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560
1980-12-29  0.64    0.015748    0.082692    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822
```

When I run

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)`

I get an error that `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

Your assistance is greatly apprecaited. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: It's exactly what the error says. You have not defined a variable X, that you want to pass to your train_test_split function.

Comment: @FlorianH thanks my friend just understood that as well, reading a example at another site. People give tutorials and leave out more than half of the stuff and they dont even say that they are leaving out half of the stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watched a lot of youtube videos for some reason they miss telling you this. Have to define X and y like:

`X = apple['Closing_Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)`

`y = apple['Daily_Returns'].values.reshape(-1,1)`